# Cannot load Image from url using picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I use piccaso 2.5.2 and I have okhttp 2.4.0 and okhttp-urlconnection 2.4.0 in my gradle. The ImageView is a part custom list item layout. The error is that nothing appears in the `ImageView`. It occurs only for the first item of the list. That list is used to populate in `SwipeFlingAdapterView` which is similar to `ListView`. `SwipeFlingAdapterView` is from this library https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards
Ok, here are my codes.

```
Picasso.with(mActivity)
                        .load(url)
                        .resize(540, 720)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(vh.iv_profile);
```

`ImageView` in xml file.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

The above code doesn't work so I try to log the error with this.

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(mActivity).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                    @Override public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Picasso","description",exception);
                    }
                }).build();

picasso.load(url)
                .resize(540, 720)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(vh.iv_profile);
```

It doesn't show error. It doesn't even get into `onImageLoadFailed`. So, I try other way around.

```
picasso.load(url)
       .resize(540, 720)
       .centerCrop()
       .into(vh.iv_profile, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                if(vh.iv_profile.getHeight() == 0){
                                    vh.iv_profile.setImageDrawable(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_default));
                                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "we get here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {

                            }
                        });
```

`OnSuccess` in callback, I can't even set Image from drawable anymore. If I set `Drawable` before using picasso.load, I can set it successfully. I also tried to use it without `.centerCrop()`. It doesn't work.
here is the final code.

```
try {
                Picasso.with(mActivity).load(url).into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                        Log.i("picasso error", "bitmap loaded");
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            vh.iv_profile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                            Log.i("picasso error", width + ", " + height);
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("picasso error", "exception");
            }
```

`onBitmapLoaded`, I get a bitmap with width and height of 243 but it doesn't appear in the ImageView.
Please help!

Comment: Did you find a solution, I am experiencing this issue as well!